# Обновление списка после ajax запроса

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

Как обновить список после отправки ajax запроса?

```
  <div id="list2">
        <h2>Все студенты</h2>
        <ul id="studentList" class="list-group" th:each="student : ${students}">
            <li><a th:href="@{/main/{id}(id=${student.getId()})}" 
               th:text="${student.getName()}">student</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

<label for="addStudent"><h3>Добавить студента</h3></label>
<form id="addStudent">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Имя">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="addStudent();" >
</form>

function addStudent() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/ajax/add_student",
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            name: $("#name").val()
        }),
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addStudent() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/ajax/add_student",
    method: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { name: $("#name").val() },
    success: function(data) {
      $("#studentList").append(data);
    } 
  });
}
```