# Передача ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Хочу передать в ссылке значение id, но как это сделать?

```
for (i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                table = table + "<tr><td>" + data[i].id +"</td><td>" + data[i].name +"</td></tr><a href='?'>Средняя оценка</a>";
        }
```

Comment: Вы вот здесь ничего не забыли сделать? - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1269873

Comment: @Igor исправил)) Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
... + data[i].name +"</td></tr><a href='?id=" + data[i].id + "'>Средняя оценка</a>";
```